# Can someone please explain the function pop (more especifically the variable retval) of the following code?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, stack, function-definition

I'm having some trouble understanding structures and would be very grateful if any of you could explain the function `pop` and what is `retval` in this context. Thank you in advance! The code is presented here:

```
 typedef struct node {
     int val;
     struct node * next;
} node_t;

int pop(node_t ** head) {
    int retval = -1;
    node_t * next_node = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    next_node = (*head)->next;
    retval = (*head)->val;
    free(*head);
    *head = next_node;

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: `retval` stands for return-value. which will be -1 (or say unsucessfull pop) when your head is `NULL` meaning `No Items to pop`.

Comment: Better hope that `-1` is never a value you wanted to store in the linked-list....

Comment: @Ana Ferreira Why do you want that somebody would explain a very bad function? You should investigate a good code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It doesn't seem so bad to me. And it's probably an example from a textbook or tutorial, so she doesn't have much choice about it.

Comment: What part of the code do you find confusing?

Comment: @Barmar Read good books instead of bad books that you read.

Comment: The function removes the first node from the list and returns its value, returning `-1` if the list is empty.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It still looks like a reasonable function to me. The only possible complaint is using a valid return value as the error indicator, but maybe negative numbers aren't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad function definition. For example its return value can confuse users of the function: whether the returned value -1 is an actual value stored in the stack or it is an error code.

There are used initializers of variables values of which are not used anywhere else within the function like for example

```
int retval = -1;
```

or

```
node_t * next_node = NULL;
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
int pop( node_t **head, int *value ) 
{
    int success = *head != NULL;

    if (success )
    {
        *value = ( *head )->val;

        node_t *tmp = *head;

        *head = ( *head )->next;

        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
node_t *head = NULL;
//...

int value;

if ( pop( &head, &value ) )
{
    printf( "The value stored on the top of the stack is %d\n", value );
}
```

Also it is convenient to use such a function in a loop. For example

```
int value;
while ( pop( &head, &value ) )
{
    printf( "%d ", value );
}
puts( "-> the stack is empty." );
```

What is the function doing?

The function pops a value that is stored on the stack. If the stack is empty

```
    int success = *head != NULL;
```

that is when `*head` is equal to `NULL` the function returns `0` - the value of the expression `*head != NULL` in this case this means for the user of the function that the stack was empty and there is nothing to pop.

Otherwise the value stored on the stack is copied in the parameter `value` and the node  that kept the value is removed from the list and its memory is freed. And the function returns the value of the variable `success` that in this case is equal to `1`.

```
    if (success )
    {
        value = ( *head )->val;

        node_t *tmp = *head;

        *head = ( *head )->next;

        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

int push( node_t **head, int value )
{
    node_t *new_node = malloc( sizeof ( node_t ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->val  = value;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

int pop( node_t **head, int *value ) 
{
    int success = *head != NULL;

    if (success )
    {
        *value = ( *head )->val;

        node_t *tmp = *head;

        *head = ( *head )->next;

        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    node_t *head = NULL;

    const int N = 10;

    int i = N;

    while ( i != 0 && push( &head, i  ) ) --i;

    int value;

    printf( "The stack contained: " );

    while ( pop( &head, &value ) )
    {
        printf( "%d ", value );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The stack contained: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```